# Where is package folder ? that should stored in android device?

Tags: java, android, directory, package-name

I am having problem i have just created a simple android app.I want to know that the folder of package name i.e. **com.xx.xx** in *Android/data* as usually created when we install an app is not present on my device how to solve this problem.
Is something that i am missing in manifest i have declared only **permission for write external storage** and everything in manifest file is same as default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I have seen the folder **com.xx.xx** in *Android/data* for the normal cases which you see only gets created if you exclusively write files to the external storage using something like [getExternalFilesDir()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String)) or [getExternalCacheDir()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getExternalCacheDir()) method. So unless you are writing it to the external storage you might be creating them as files stored privately by the application.

If you are looking for these files stored privately by the application, i don't think these are shown by the default file browser in an unrooted device. But in an emulator or device connected to android studio, you can use "Device File Explorer".

If you don't see its tab, go to: View --> Tool Windows --> Device File Explorer.

In the Device File Explorer, Select your device then expand: data --> data --> com.xx.xx

And within it you should be able to see the privately generated files.

Also for us to understand what you are actually using, there is no way unless you add the code of how you are writing these files you mentioned.